# Determining when a linear transformation is an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, linear-transformations

[image]

Hi,

I know that $$ \langle v,w\rangle $$ satisfies the first three conditions of being an inner product always. As such, the only condition that needs to be met is

$$ T(v) \cdot T(v) > 0 $$

This is true when $T(v)$ is non-zero. But the answer in the back of the book says this is true when the $ker(T) = 0$. Can someone explain what this means?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what ker(T) means? It's the kernel. Do you see why having a non-zero kernel is a problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\ker T \neq \{0\}$, so there is some vector $v \in \ker T$, which means $T(v) = 0$. Then
$$
\langle v, v \rangle = T(v) \cdot T(v) = 0
$$
but $v \neq 0$, which contradicts positive-definiteness of inner-products.